# Translate CPQ Quote Template Content

Tags: cpq, translation, template, quote-template

[image]Unable to use '**Template Content Variable**' while translating Template Content record.

Requirement is I need to translate text in my template content to specific languages on quote document.

Please refer to the image attached with this post.

Have also referred to this Salesforce docs page here [Translate CPQ Quote Template Content](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.cpq_translate_template_content.htm&type=5)
. The example is not clear. How can we create template content variable, get it translated and show it on quote template document?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Eventually, we saw this Translate button on the Quote Template record itself, and put our translations there.  It worked after that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes that works.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong variable name in the translate page. Just put in `currencyused`. Then in your template you need to use the merge syntax `{!text.currencyused}`

Comment: Thanks for help @Daniel Hoechst. It worked.!

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with capital T  `{!Text.VariableName}`. I hope this recommendation helps anyone